# Adding language to Ubiquity

Tags: ubiquity

Can't get to work ubiquity as I want. It's like no other locale exists. I switch to spanish and nothing changes. If I hit 'Try', it loads the live in spanish, but if I hit Install, the installer is in english -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjCvv.jpg

Note: In my isolinux loader I have the parameters 'maybe-ubiquity' and 'locale=es_ES'

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubiquity, then when you boot from the .iso (If created) or start the setup, it should ask you if you want to setup as Spanish or English. If that didn't help, [I recommend going here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity). Hope I helped. :)

Comment: Yes, that's my problem, when I select Spanish nothing changes. It's like it lacks some locale :S

Comment: Hmm.. try the website I put in the answer above, but what program are you using?